# How do I capture information from a website that doesn't provide an API?

Tags: html, api, parsing, web-scraping

Do you know any good tutorials, frameworks, anything that can help me to write code that captures information from a website that don't have a public API, or hasn't been written in a RESTful way?

I've heard there's a Ruby gem that simulates a browser, but I forgot its name and couldn't find any information about it anymore.

Comment: This is contradictory--the title asks about non-RESTful sites, then you ask about websites "written in a RESTful way".  Which is it?

Comment: Sorry! It should be 'hasn't been written in a RESTful way'! ;)

Comment: You can look into [HTTrack](http://www.httrack.com/) to see how they do it.

Answer (score 5):

There are a variety of Ruby libraries for parsing (X)HTML into a structured format. Two of the oldest and most popular libraries for this are [Hpricot](https://github.com/hpricot/hpricot) and [Nokogiri](https://github.com/tenderlove/nokogiri). These libraries provide a variety of capabilities for working with HTML data.

A few things to keep in mind when doing this:

- Respect copyright! site authors likely won't be happy about people scraping data from their sites and using it without permission. Ask first!
- Changes can break things easily. If they change the structure of your site, your code will likely blow up if not written properly.

Comment: +1 for those two bullet points, which you absolutely *must* keep in mind if doing anything like this.

Comment: I plan on index prices from online stores. Is it something copyrightable?

Comment: @JoãoDaniel: Technically they can stop you, either by legal or technical means (eg. constantly making subtle changes). But they probably won't IF you are offering some value to them by doing whatever you're doing. Look to the biggest player in the market; they are the one who won't appreciate you advertising other companies to their customers. If you can convince them it's in their interest, you'll be fine; otherwise don't waste your time.

Answer (score 0):

Well, for Java you can use the apache HttpClient library, which will allow you to (easily) make http calls and cope with sessions and the like.  Likewise, .NET has an class called... HttpClient.

Consuming the response, if you don't have some sort of predefined arrangement, will require you to set some expectations (it can't really be TOTALLY arbitrary) and do some parsing to glean information from the response you get.

I can't speak to Ruby, but I'm guessing there's something similar in most modern languages.